# Replace string after specific character php

Tags: php, string

I have this string with student names and grades
`student1: A, B, D; student2: A, A, C; student3: F, F, D`
How can I update student1(or any other student) grades to his current grades plus an A(or any other grade)?

Comment: Why are you doing this by updating the string? You should have the data in an array, update the array, and then generate the string from that.

Comment: anyway, you can do what you want with `preg_replace()`. Use a pattern that matches the student name followed by any grades. Replace it with the string containing the new grades.